# Windows 10 Update can't connect

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to update a Windows 10 (IoT LSTC Enterprise) PC and am seeing the following errors:

"Your device is missing important security and quality fixes.

We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet."

I am certainly connected to the internet. I've tried several things involving enabling/disabled windows update-related services, but have had no luck. I believe that somewhere there's a policy setting blocking the settings app from accessing the url/connection it pulls windows updates from, but I don't know where to find that. Any guidance on what could cause this issue appreciated.

Comment: What build are you currently running?  If you manually download the current cumulative update, from the [Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) are you able to install the update? The policy you speak of, wouldn't generate the message, that you are recieving even if it was enabled.

Comment: Build was from last fall, I was able to do that and the update installed via wusa.exe, though that still doesn't clear up why I'm seeing this issue

Comment: Were all Windows Update related services enable or disabled when you attempted to disable and reenable them? A build from last fall isn't specific enough.

Comment: Upload the Windows Update log for us